# array_shift() not recognizing array variable

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, html

I created a Web App for a Delivery service. It incorporates google maps as well as queries a database for open deliveries. The problem is that when I hooked up a button to shift the delivery array by array_shift() through an ajax call, is wont recognize the array.

```
<?php
session_start();
require 'ConnectTest.php';

// IF YOU'RE NOT LOGGED IN, KICK BACK TO LOGIN SCREEN
if(!isset($_SESSION['username']) || !isset($_SESSION['password'])){
  header("Location:signin.php");
}

$servername = "localhost:3306";
$user = "sonic_client";
$pass = "client";
$dbName = "sonicStrains";

$drop = "DROP TABLE ".$_SESSION['username']."_deliveries";
mysqli_query($server, $drop);

//CREATE INDIVIDUAL DRIVER TABLE TO HOLD DELIVERIES
$createQuery = "CREATE TABLE ".$_SESSION['username']."_deliveries (
                transaction_id VARCHAR(13),
                timePaid INT(11),
                username VARCHAR(30),
                user_location VARCHAR(255),
                user_lat float(10,6),
                user_long float(10,6),
                item_name VARCHAR(20),
                item_quantity float,
                driver_username VARCHAR(60),
                driver_lat float(10,6),
                driver_long float(10,6),
                on_delivery tinyint(1))"
;

$created = mysqli_query($server, $createQuery);

if ($created){

  //query the deliveries for open deliveries up untill 5 deliveries
  $queryString = "SELECT * FROM deliveries LIMIT 5";

  $query = mysqli_query($server, $queryString);

  if($query){

    // CREATE ARRAY TO HOLD QUERY ROWS
    $rows = array();

    while($queryresult = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
      $rows = $queryresult;
    }


    //INSERT & UPDATE THE TABLES WITH DELIVERY QUERIES
    foreach($rows as $row){

      // INSERT INTO INDIVIDUAL DRIVER TABLE
      $insertQuery = "INSERT INTO ".$_SESSION['username']."_deliveries (transaction_id, user_location, user_lat, user_long) VALUES('$row[transaction_id]', '$row[user_location]', '$row[user_lat]', '$row[user_long]')";

      $insertExec = mysqli_query($server, $insertQuery);

      // UPDATE MASTER LIST OF DELIVERIES SO THAT OTHER DRIVERS DONT QUERY SAME ORDER
      $updateQuery = "UPDATE deliveries SET on_delivery=true, driver_username='$_SESSION[driver_id]' WHERE transaction_id='$row[transaction_id]'";
      $updateExec = mysqli_query($server, $updateQuery);
    }

  }else{echo mysqli_error($server);}


}else{echo mysqli_error($server);}


if(isset($_GET['pop'])){
  array_shift($rows);
}

echo<<<_

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
  <style> /* the stylesheet below */ </style>
</head> 

<body>

  <div class="Banner">
      <div class="TitleText">Sonic Strains &copy;</div>
  </div>


  <div class="login">Logout</div>
  <div class="gallery" id="container">
      <div class="map" id="mapInsert"></div>
      <div class="navButton">Start Nav</div><div class="orderButton">Order Details</div>
      <div class="abortButton">Abort</div><div class="confirmButton" onclick="shiftOrder()">Confirm</div><div class="disclaimer"></div>
  </div>


  <script>
      function initMap() {

        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {

            var initialLocation = {lat:$rows[user_lat], lng:$rows[user_long]};
            var Map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapInsert'));
            Map.setCenter(initialLocation);
            Map.setZoom(13);
            // MAKE ANOTHER MARKER FOR THE CLIENT LOCATION
                    var userLocation = {lat:$rows[user_lat], lng:$rows[user_long]};
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position:userLocation, 
                        map:Map,
                        draggable:false, 
                        clickable:false
                        });
                    marker.setMap(Map);

        }, function(positionError) {

        //---------- User denied geolocation prompt - default to Chicago

        Map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(39.8097343, -98.5556199));
        Map.setZoom(5);
      },{enableHighAccuracy:true, timeout: 3000, maximumAge:1000});

      } 

      function shiftOrder(){

          var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
          http.onreadystatechange = function(){
              console.log(this.responseText);

          }
          http.open("GET", "driverIndex.php?pop='pop'", true);
          http.send();

      }

  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=KEY&callback=initMap" 
      async defer></script>

</body>
</html>

_;

?>
```

I have called print_r($rows) and it returns values as it should. I even use it to reference lat & long in my Google Maps, so why can't array_shift($rows) work?

If needed to reproduce my example above, here is the used CSS stylesheet:

```
.TitleText{
  font-size:200%;
}

.Banner{                                      /*This is test code to hold the top ad*/
  width:100%;
  text-align:center;
  border-style:solid;
  border-color:grey;
  color:green;
  font-size:230%;
  font-weight:heavy;
  letter-spacing:1px;
}

.TopNav{

  margin-top:20px;
}

a:link{
  text-decoration:none;
}

.login{
  margin-top:15px;
  margin-right:15px;
  float:right;
  border-style:solid;
  border-color:grey;
  border-radius:10px;
  background-color:blue;
  color:white;
  font-size:30px;

}

.gallery{                                         /*This will hold the gallery Items*/
  text-align:center;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: 16px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: green;
}

.map{
  width:100%;
  height:400px;
  border-style:solid;
}

.navButton{
  background-color:green;
  color:white;
  font-size:30px;
  margin-top: 16px;
  text-align:center;
  width:100%;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius:10px;
  border-style:solid;
  border-color:red;
}

.orderButton{
  background-color:green;
  color:white;
  font-size:30px;
  margin-top: 16px;
  text-align:center;
  float:right;
  display: inline-block;
  border-style:solid;
  border-right:red;
  border-color:purple;
  border-radius:10px;
  width:100%;
  height:auto;

}

.abortButton{
  background-color:green;
  color:white;
  font-size:30px;
  margin-top: 16px;
  text-align:center;
  border-style:solid;
  border-color:yellow;
  border-radius:10px;
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
  display: inline-block;
}

.confirmButton{
  background-color:green;
  color:white;
  font-size:30px;
  margin-top: 16px;
  text-align:center;
  border-style:solid;
  border-color:pink;
  border-radius:10px;
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
  display: inline-block;
}

h1{
  font-weight:bold;
}


h3{
  font-weight:bold;
  color:green;
}

.disclaimer{
  width:100%;
  height:30px;

  border-style:solid;
  border-radius:10px;
  border-color:grey;
  text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: Please read about [**SQL injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Instead of building queries with string concatenation, use [**prepared statements**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) with [**bound parameters**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php). See [**this page**](https://phptherightway.com/#databases) and [**this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) for some good examples.

Comment: Why wont the array_shift() work?

Comment: `array_shift()` pops the first item off the front of an array and returns it, leaving the array one item shorter. You're not using the return value of the function or the array after it's been modified. What are you expecting to happen? Usually you'd have something like `$firstItem = array_shift($list);`

Comment: You should update code as if(isset($_GET['pop'])){  $rows = array_shift($rows); }

Comment: Also note, the day-to-day operation of your app should never include schema changes. I.e., you shouldn't be adding/removing a delivery table per driver. Instead, have a delivery table for all drivers, keyed by driver_id.

Comment: You could also skip the `array_shift()` and just use `$rows[0][user_lat]` to explicitly reference the elements of the first row.

Comment: I called array_shift($rows) which should pop the 1st element thus loading the next set of lat and long coordinates. The map remains the same though.

Comment: I want to use array_shift() because that element will no longer be needed. Simply looping through array without "popping" wont do.

Comment: correct, I forgot to reference the return value as he new array. How would I replace that array with the old array that currently hold the lat & long?

Comment: No, the return value is *not* the new array, it's a single item. The existing array is changed in place. I.e., you're popping the first element and then throwing it away, leaving you with the next four in `$rows`, which you're then treating as if it were a single element. You're using `$rows['user_lat']` but that won't work because `$rows` is still an array, not a single item from the array. You need to either iterate over the rows like `foreach ($rows as $row) {` or explicitly reference one row like `$rows[0]['user_lat']`

Comment: If $rows['user_lat'] has changed why wont it reflect in the Google Map? Shouldn't it reflect the new element? Could u type out a visualization to help

Comment: In your code `$rows` is a numbered array of all fetched rows by the query `SELECT * FROM deliveries LIMIT 5`. Conditionally it is reduced to max. 4 rows, removing the first. So `$rows['user_lat']` should not be defined at all, but `$rows[0]['user_lat']` to `$rows[4]['user_lat']`

Comment: Btw.: Prepared statements can not parameterize `INSERT INTO ".$_SESSION['username']."_deliveries` and `mysqli_real_escape_string` will not help much to sanitize. You have to enclose the table name into backticks  `\`tablename\`` and properly escape the name also taking potential encoding attacks into account. If somehow possible you should avoid dynamic table names at all.

Comment: QUASI, $rows should be a associative array, why are you calling it a numbered array?

Comment: Ok, I see the line `$rows = $queryresult;` actually overwrites `$rows` with the latest fetched columns. This way the entire code does not seem to make sense, refrained from the fact that semantically the variable names do not express their purpose.

Comment: To fetch the **fifths row only**, the query could be as well `SELECT * FROM deliveries LIMIT 4,1` (zero-based count => 4)

Comment: Could you tell me how I would go about referencing the new value of $rows after the array_shift($rows)

Comment: The question is what you **really** want to achieve. There does not seam to be any reason to remove a *column* by position from the associative array.

Comment: $rows is an array filled with associative arrays. array_shift() should remove an array, not the column.  ie $rows[0]['user_lat'] not $rows['user_lat']

Comment: Above you said 'QUASI, $rows should be a associative array', now you say '$rows is an array filled with associative arrays ... ie $rows[0]' meaning `$rows` would be a numbered array containing e.g. [0]. You are confused. In fact you overwrite `$rows` with the latest fetched row, thus containing only columns as associative array. see `$rows = $queryresult;` in your code. You propably intended `$rows[] = $queryresult;` to append to the array.

Comment: Referencing $rows[0][column_name] returns an error -- 'user_lat' undefined. -- But it works when I call $rows['user_lat']. Calling $rows[0]['user_lat'] doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if it could not be conclusively clarified in the comment discussion, you propably expected the code

```
while($queryresult = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
  $rows = $queryresult;
}
```

to add new rows as entries to the array. In fact it *overwrites* the variable with an associative array containing the *latest* row, i.e. columns.

To get an array of rows, use

```
while($queryresult = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
  $rows[] = $queryresult;
}
```

This will *append* array items to the existing array.

Comment: should I declare $rows = array(); outside of the loop, or just $rows[ ] = $old_array; inside of the loop?

Comment: Explicitly declaring and initializing variables is always a good code style. Yes, of course outside the loop.

Comment: @SonicStrains not `=$old_array` but `= $new_item`, i.e. the query result. `$existing_array[] = $new_item;`

Comment: Your solution worked to load up the queries, but now I'm having trouble referencing the lat & long. I've tried $rows[0][4], $rows[0][5] (LatLng) and I tried $rows[0]['user_lat'], $rows[0]['user_long'] and both didn't properly reference the coordinates.

Comment: What does a `var_dump($rows);` actually output? The output should already answer your question.

Comment: Array ( [0] => Array ( [transaction_id] => 5c2fb27078926 [timePaid] => 0 [username] => [user_location] => 1301 Bataan St NW, Washington, DC 20036, USA [user_lat] => 38.907246 [user_long] => -77.037292 [item_name] => girl_scout_cookies [item_quantity] => 1 [driver_username] => [driver_lat] => 0.000000 [driver_long] => 0.000000 [on_delivery] => 1 )  etc etc etc

Comment: At the point of print_r `$rows[0]['user_lat']` is `38.907246`.

Comment: i used that ($rows[0]['user_lat']) as the reference for LatLng but it said                       --"user_lat is not a number" --  but LatLng was perfectly fine when it was just $rows['user_lat']. Why the fuss all of a sudden now?

Comment: Try `var_dump`.

Comment: i tried var _dump, it said it's a "string", but that doesn't explain why that same* string was okay to use when the array was simply $rows['user_lat'].  It's the same array is it not. Why not accept the value now when it changed to $rows[0]['user_lat'] ?

Comment: Not clear why it should have worked correctly before (showing the correct number) but `(double) $row['user_lat']` explicitly casts the type into a number.

Comment: @SonicStrains We should stop breaking the SO rules by discussing many code problems at once. SO is meant to answer one specific issue per question. You should open a new question touching a specific issue if you run into further problems after solving one.

Comment: will do, thanx.